# Syntax Error in Python compiling (Mac Os - Terminal)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, compiler-errors

I just watched a video on YouTube in which they discuss about the maths of the Monopoly game, and besides all the things, they added the Python code in the download box, hence I downloaded it to try it...

This is the code:

```
import random
from random import shuffle

def monop(finish_order=6,games_order=3):

    finish = 10**finish_order
    games = 10**games_order

    squares = []

    while len(squares) < 40:
        squares.append(0)

    # roll values are values from a six by six grid for all dice rolls
    rollvalues = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,8,9,10,6,7,8,9,10,11,7,8,9,10,11,12]

    games_finished = 0

    while games_finished < games:

        master_chest = [0,40,40,40,40,10,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40]
        chest = [i for i in master_chest]
        shuffle(chest)

        master_chance = [0,24,11,'U','R',40,40,'B',10,40,40,5,39,40,40,40]
        chance = [i for i in master_chance]
        shuffle(chance)

        doubles = 0

        position = 0

        gos = 0

        while gos < finish:

            diceroll = int(36*random.random())

            if diceroll in [0,7,14,21,28,35]:    # these are the dice index values for double rolls
                doubles += 1
            else:
                doubles = 0
            if doubles >= 3:
                position = 10
            else:

                position = (position + rollvalues[diceroll])%40

                if position in [7,22,33]:  # Chance
                    chance_card = chance.pop(0)
                    if len(chance) == 0:
                        chance = [i for i in master_chance]
                        shuffle(chance)
                    if chance_card != 40:

                        if isinstance(chance_card,int):
                            position = chance_card
                        elif chance_card == 'U':
                            while position not in [12,28]:
                                position = (position + 1)%40
                        elif chance_card == 'R':
                            while position not in [5,15,25,35]:
                                position = (position + 1)%40
                        elif chance_card == 'B':
                            position = position - 3

                elif position in [2,17]:  # Community Chest
                    chest_card = chest.pop(0)
                    if len(chest) == 0:
                        chest = [i for i in master_chest]
                        shuffle(chest)
                    if chest_card != 40:
                        position = chest_card

                if position == 30: # Go to jail
                    position = 10


            squares.insert(position,(squares.pop(position)+1))

            gos += 1

        games_finished += 1


    return squares
```

Called: monopoly-v1.py

Now, when I try to compile and run it into the terminal I get "problems".

By writing

```
python monopoly-v1.py
```

in the terminal, I don't get any error or warning, but it does not happen anything...

If I try with

```
python monopoly-v1.py
```

and then

```
./monopoly-v1.py
```

then here is what it says:

./monopoly-v1.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./monopoly-v1.py: line 1:`def monop(finish_order=6,games_order=3):'

I don't understand what is wrong. By the way, python or python3 are the same, I mean: no error appears at the first step.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: The code you've presented consists of just one Python function. There's no code to 'make it go', so to speak.

Answer (score 4):

This code is merely a function definition and some imports. It will do  nothing if you don't *run that function*. This is why `python script.py` doesn't show anything.

Now, when you try to do this:

```
./script.py
```

The shell tries to execute Python code as if it was written in BASH (or, more generally, as if it was a *shell script*), which results in an error, of course. Why does it do so? Because it's *told* to execute via the `./` structure, but cannot find anything to execute it with<sup>1</sup>. So, it finally tries to run it as a shell script.

---

<sub>1. And the shell actually does the search. For example, if you prefixed your code with a special *shebang*, it would try to run it as Python code: `#!python` or `#!env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python` or even `#!/path/to/python`</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You have not called any function you wish to execute. If you would like to call the `monop` function from the command line, you might do so by using the `-c` argument:

```
$ python -c 'from monopoly-v1 import monop; print monop(6, 3)'
```

Note that the print function syntax will be different if using Python 3:

```
$ python -c 'from monopoly-v1 import monop; print(monop(6, 3))'
```

Comment: What is your syntax error? The command line syntax here is correct.

Comment: File "<string>", line 1
    from monopoly-v1.py import monop; print monop(6, 3)
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using python 3?

Comment: I can use both of them, if you are asking about what version does my computer support

Comment: I am asking which version you are using to attempt to run this code, clearly; >> print(foo) is python 3 syntax, >>print foo only works in python 2

Answer (score 2):

just add:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    monop()
```

at the end of monopoly-v1.py

Comment: I tried to do that, but when I compile it takes forever (no response..)

Comment: @ForceBru I don't think your comment helped me somehow.